# Storing state in array React-Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am new to react-redux so bear with me please.. I am trying to have a user create a note which will then be stored into an array that I can map through to display on the page as they create notes. I'm having difficulties trying to do so... It only works when i store it as an object but then I can't loop through with the map function..

**Notes Reducer:**

```
const initialState = {
  notes: [],
};

export default function (state = initialState, action) {
  const { type, payload } = action;

  switch (type) {
    case GET_NOTES:
      return {
        ...state,
        notes: payload,
      };
    case NOTE_ADDED:
      return {
        ...state,
        notes: payload,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

**Notes Action:**

```
// Get Notes
export const getNotes = (notes) => {
  return {
    type: GET_NOTES,
    payload: notes,
  };
}:

// Add Note
export const addNote = (formData) => async (dispatch) => {
  const body = JSON.stringify(formData);

  try {
    const res = await api.post('/notes', body);

    dispatch({
      type: NOTE_ADDED,
      payload: res.data,
    });
    dispatch(setAlert('Note Added', 'success'));
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    const errors = err.response.data.errors;

    if (errors) {
      errors.forEach((error) => dispatch(setAlert(error.msg, 'error')));
    }

    dispatch({
      type: NOTE_ERROR,
    });
  }
};
```

**notes.js**

```
const Notes = ({ addNote, notes }) => {
  const onSubmit = (values) => {
    addNote(values);
  };

  console.log(notes);

  const renderNotes = (notes) => {
    if (!notes) {
      return <h4>There are no notes</h4>;
    } else {
      return notes.map((note) => (
        <>
          {note.note.name}
          {note.note.email}
          {note.note.phone}
        </>
      ));
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      {renderNotes()}
      <div>
        <Alerts />
        <h1>Add a Note</h1>
        <Form layout="vertical" name="login-form" onFinish={onSubmit}>
          <Form.Item name="name" label="Name">
            <Input placeholder="Enter Name" />
          </Form.Item>
          <Form.Item name="Email" label="Email">
            <Input placeholder="Enter Email" />
          </Form.Item>
          <Form.Item name="phone" label="Phone">
            <Input placeholder="Enter Phone" />
          </Form.Item>
          <Form.Item>
            <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit" block>
              Login
            </Button>
          </Form.Item>
        </Form>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  notes: state.notes,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { addNote })(Notes);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your reducer should look like this, if I'm getting you right.

```
    switch (type) {
      case GET_NOTES:
        return {
          notes: [...state.notes, payload]
        };
      case NOTE_ADDED:
        return {
            notes: [...state.notes, payload]
        };
      default:
        return state;
    }
```

You should try to use [Redux Toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/introduction/quick-start) with react-redux as it reduces a lot of redux boilerplate and makes dealing with reducers actions simpler.

Comment: When doing this i get: Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

Comment: from the code you posted data is a property of the response from the api call, so that is likely an error source you should console the response of `await api.post('/notes', body)` to see if it is what you expect.